# HTML - How to get selection offsets with relatives to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose my HTML looks something like this

```
<div>
    <p> start<span>span</span>end </p>
</div>
```

I need to be be able to get the offsets when a selection is made, without ignoring the span tags.

e.g.
suppose to user selected

```
t<span>span</span>e
```

I want the to get 4 as starting offset and 24 as the ending offset.
The selection object obtained via window.getSelection() returns 1,8, which is rather useless to me.
I obviously need to handle all cases where the user selects only the inner span, or part of the span etc.

Thanks

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007357/jquery-get-selections-paragraph-length-etc) [jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/wP8w9/2/)

Comment: I've tried fiddling around with the example, but I can't figure out how to get the actual offsets...

Comment: sorry, my bad... I'll take a look then I get home.

Comment: (Basically I need the offset from the start of the wrapping span to its father)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up solving it thusly:

```
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            // inserts two spans at the beginning and end of the range, to
            // calculate the offsets
            var div = document.createElement("span");
            div.setAttribute("class", START_NODE);
            range.insertNode(div);
            range.collapse(false);
            div = document.createElement("span");
            div.setAttribute("class", END_NODE);
            range.insertNode(div);
            // gets the offsets by looking up the location of the inserted spans
            // removes them after finding the offsets (also so the starting
            // offset won't screw up the ending offset)
            comment.startOffset = p.html().indexOf('<span class="' + START_NODE + '">');
            $("." + START_NODE).remove();
            comment.endOffset = p.html().indexOf('<span class="' + END_NODE + '">');
            $("." + END_NODE).remove();
            p.html(p.html());
```

basically, I've added a SPAN at the beginning of the range selection, then collapsed the range and added a SPAN at the end of it.
Then I simply searched for the index of the first span I've added, and the index of the second span I've added to find the offsets.